# SQL Azure support in Arabic Language

Tags: sql, azure

Do we have support for arabic language in sql azure database? Basically we need to store the data of arabic language for CRUD operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is Yes you have.

[This table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336233.aspx) shows the datatypes supported in SQL Azure. The datatypes `nchar`, `nvarchar` and `ntext` are all [unicode](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), thus support the arabic language.